# Question on best practice for creating views that are consumed by visualization tools like PowerBI or Tableau

Tags: sql, database, data-visualization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view

I've tried searching around to see what the best practices are when designing a view that will be used for visualization going directly into PowerBI or Tableau.

I don't know the best way to ask this but is there an issue with creating a big query 30+ columns with multiple joins in the DB for export into the visualization platform? I've seen some posts regarding size and about breaking up into multiple queries but those are also in reference to bringing into some program and writing logic in the program to do the joins etc.

I have tried both ways so far, smaller views that I then create relationships in PowerBI or larger views where I'm dealing with one just flat table. I realize that in most respects PowerBI can do a star scheme with data being brought in but I've also run into weird issues with filtering within the PowerBI itself, that I have been able to alleviate and speed up by doing that work in the DB instead.

Database is a Snowflake warehouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever possible, you should be using the underlying database to do the work that databases are good at i.e. selecting/filtering/aggregating data. So your BI tools should be querying those tables rather than bringing all the data into the BI tool as one big dataset and then letting the BI tool process it